# CFWheels Unit Testing?

Tags: coldfusion, cfwheels

I have searched Google and abroad and I cannot find anything about CFWheels Unit Testing. Does anyone know if it exists and if so can you point me in the right direction?

Thanks,
Darren

Comment: http://cfwheels.org/blog/getting-started-video-tutorial/

Comment: Well, I've tried unsuccessfully 10 times to delete the above comment, so I'm giving up.  cfwheels has their own suite of unit tests, you might try checking those out: http://code.google.com/p/cfwheels/wiki/RunningFrameworkUnitTests

Comment: Oh, I thought that was just for the framework itself?

Comment: It is, but looking at the code might give you some clues about how your own code can be unit tested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will more than likely be an "experimental" feature in 1.1 and refined in maintenance releases like 1.1.1 (though the functionality is there supposedly).

Unfortunately, our priorities have been in other areas, and we haven't been able to put unit testing of Wheels apps themselves through its paces and get it documented. I'll be sure to update this page as I get more info.

Comment: yeah... my bad on this one as i still haven't had the time to write the instructions.

Comment: rip747: A man that puts as many hours into the project as you do should _not_ apologize for anything! :)